# Is there an in-universe reason why so many people in Altered Carbon are following late 20th/early 21st century fashion?

Tags: cyberpunk, altered-carbon

Given that Altered Carbon happens several centuries in the future, why do so many people wear clothes that look very close to, or identical to, late 20th century/early 21st century styles?

Out-of-universe, it's part of the cyberpunk aesthetic, but is there an in-universe reason?

Comment: You do realise that jeans and T-shirts are a 1940s aesthetic still prevalent in 2020?

Comment: Probably the same reason why all the girls on Original Series Star Trek were wearing skirts, but later Trek series shifted towards unisex uniforms.  Predicting what the future will bring is a function of present day sensibilities.

Comment: The standard men's business suit was basically established in the 1880s, with the absence of a waistcoat/vest and shortening it being the only significant changes in the present day, and even then, vests aren't unusual.

Comment: I haven't watched the entire series, but seeing as how people's consciousness can be suspended for extended periods of time, I would think changes in fashion trends would slow to a crawl. Were I to wake up 100 years from today, I would still look for the clothes I wore "yesterday".

Comment: Because wardrobe is expensive.